# How to scroll the webpages horizantally when navigation button is clicked?

Tags: javascript

I have spent the last days looking for a simple javascript or jquery code for this. I want to incorporate a horizontal scrolling when navigation button is clicked ,The pages content should move left to right.

It would function very similar to the scrolling shown here:

http://codecanyon.net/item/fss-full-screen-sliding-website-plugin/full_screen_preview/159103

Comment: Why can't you just use the jQuery plugin that you linked?

Comment: Or alternatively: have a parent container div with position: relative and inside the different pages as individual divs with position: absolute; and float: left, and then animate the left or right css property of the container div. It's fun to build this yourself :)

Comment: Yeah i can use.. but the problem is am using slides show if i use jquery pluging it wont works@ Matt Bradley

Answer (score 1):

Try the scrollLeft and/or scrollTop methods:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollLeft

Use it in a nested container:

```
<div id="myDiv" style="width:100px;overflow:hidden">
 <div>LONGTEXTLONGTEXTLONGTEXTLONGTEXTLONGTEXTLONGTEXTLONGTEXTLONGTEXT...</div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="document.getElementById('myDiv').scrollLeft += 10" value="Scroll!"/>
```